# Implement suppression list in Exim for some senders only

Tags: debian, email-server, exim, debian-stretch

I have an Exim router that for some senders delivers mail via a smarthost:

```
send_via_ses:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = ses_smtp
  route_list = * email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com;
  senders = lsearch;/etc/exim4/ses-senders
```

I am required to maintain a list of recipients known to bounce, messages for which Exim should do the bounce instead of trying to send via the smarthost. If the *sender* is not on the senders list, mail is not delivered via the smarthost, and the message should not be bounced.

How can I implement this?